How do I select an InputField with the new InputSystem during a UnitTest?
I'm trying to integrate Unit testing for my UI (Play Mode test) and I saw that the new InputSystem support automated input testing.
I check the manual and the samples in github repository but I can't understand exactly how to setup my test.
I tried to implement a simple UnityTest method where I set the position of the virtual Mouse on top of the InputField, then I Press and Release its left button.
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator InputSystem_MovePointerAndClickInputField_InputFieldIsSelected()
{
    // Arrange
    var inputField = GameObject.FindFirstObjectByType<TMP_InputField>();
    var inputFieldRect = inputField.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    var fieldScreenPosition = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(Camera.main, inputFieldRect.position);

    var mouse = InputSystem.AddDevice<Mouse>();

    // Act
    Set(mouse.position, fieldScreenPosition);
    Press(mouse.leftButton);
    Release(mouse.leftButton);
    yield return null;

    // Assert
    Assert.That(inputField.isFocused, Is.True);
}

But the assert result is False.
EDIT: After @derHugo's comment I decided opt out from simulating user input.
Now I use TMP_InputField.Select() directly, then TMP_InputField.ProcessEvent() to type in the text I wanted:
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator InputSystem_MovePointerAndClickInputField_InputFieldIsSelected()
{
    // Arrange
    var inputField = GameObject.FindFirstObjectByType<TMP_InputField>();
    var inputFieldRect = inputField.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    // Act
    inputField.Select();
    yield return null;
    Assert.That(inputField.isFocused, Is.True);

    string textInput = "I typed this text";
    foreach (char c in textInput)
    {
        inputField.ProcessEvent(Event.KeyboardEvent($"{c}"));
        inputField.ForceLabelUpdate();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
    }

    // Assert
    Assert.That(inputField.text, Is.EqualTo(textInput));
}


Question though: Why would you write a unit test for testing a functionality of the TMP_InputField itself? Shouldn't you rely on TMP itself behaving as expected? or is this rather a test whether something is overlaying and blocking input? In that case a simple GraphicsRaycaster.RaycastAll (it is attached to the canvas by default) should be enough ...

Also if the UI is in a screenspace overlay canvas then its position already IS in screenspace and the conversion via WorldToScreenPoint will probably result in insanely large values ...

@derHugo I wanted to recreate a "virtual" user interaction with the UI, but I'm probably making my life more difficult, am I?

Just assume everything in Unity is already tested so you don't need to care for it. You would test your own code and inject some mock input, but testing if the Update runs every frame or other Unity functionalities is a waste of time. First coz as I said it works, and second because if it didn't, you couldn't fix it anyway. Focus on your code and inject what you think could be passed to it.

In your case, you know the InputField works. So, testing if the field contains the values you entered is not necessary. What you would test is how your system would react based on the given input. Say you need a birthdate, then you would check different input and unit test the output. "01.01.1900" or "01-01-1900", "01011900" or "aabbccdd" and your code would manipulate this information and based on its content, do something. But not the InputField validation.
